# Networking layout and multiple DHCP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, dhcp

So I got an assignment where I have to design a local network for my school.

Here's what I have :

- ZTE F660 WRouter from my provider, connected to internet via fiber
- SG1008P Switch
- EAP 110 A, for clients and library (perpustakaan)
- EAP 110 B, for clients and mess/mushollah

Here's what I want :

- ZTE F660 connects to the switch, to share internet with EAP 110 A & B, and the computers in "Ruangan Guru" & "Perpustakaan", and also connects to server for other purposes
- EAP 110 A to have 2 SSIDs, one for the clients on the left and right side of the building with 172.168.20.x subnet, and one for the library with 172.168.40.x subnet. And it will be using a static IP (172.168.20.1) from ZTE
- EAP 110 B to have 2 SSIDs, first SSID is for the clients on the left and right side of the building with 172.168.30.x subnet, and second one is for the guests in mushollah with 172.168.50.x subnet. And the device itself will be using a static IP (172.168.30.1)

The question is :

- Can I have DHCP server on EAP110 A & B while also having a DHCP server on the ZTE ? If can't, then how can I keep the IP settings as planned (assuming that is is possible to keep it that way)?
- Can I use different sets of IP for each SSID on the same device? (ex: 172.168.30.x for SSID 1 and 172.168.50.x for SSID 2).

I think I can skip all the headache and get another access point each for the library and mushollah but it seems like a waste of money, not to mention I still got the multiple DHCP problem. Please help if you got some improvements or better ideas, thanks !

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO5Zm.png)

Answer (score 1):

- No. EAP110 is an AP, not a Router. It has no DHCP server function.
- Yes. EAP110's multiple SSIDs can work with VLAN, and you can use different IP sets in different VLANs.
  But, you also need a switch which supports VLAN and DHCP Relay (SG1008P doesn't) and a DHCP server which can support multiple subnets (I don't think ZTE F660 can). Or you may try using a PC with 3 network interfaces instead of the VLAN switch and the DHCP server.